# Does hajj erase missed fasting and prayers?

Tags: salat, sawm, hajj, salat-qada

If someone had missed many days of fasting in Ramadan and had some missed prayers.

This person went and did Hajj successfully.

Will this person's past missed days of fasting and prayer be erased?

Answer (score 1):

There exist ahadith which say that Hajj erases past sins:

> من حج لله فلم يرفث ولم يفسق رجع كيوم ولدته أمه
>
> Whoever performs Hajj for Allah's pleasure and without talking immodestly or acting wickedly, he will return [free from sin] as on the day his mother bore him.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1521) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1350a)</sup>

> الحج يهدم ما كان قبله
>
> Hajj destroys whatever (misdeeds) came before it.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:121)</sup>

Now, if you missed an obligatory fast or prayer then two things happen:

- you earn sin for delaying the act of worship
- fulfilling the obligation becomes a debt which you have to perform later

Performing Hajj can erase the sin, but it does not waive the obligation. So if you are able to perform Qada' (قضاء) of the missed fasts and prayers then you must still do that.

And if you are able to perform the previously missed fast\prayer but continue to delay performing it then you would again start earning sin for delaying it.

---

**Ref:**

> وقال الدميري في الحديث الصحيح "من حج فلم يرفث ولم يفسق خرج من ذنوبه كيوم ولدته أمه" : وهو مخصوص بالمعاصي المتعلقة بحقوق الله تعالى خاصة، دون العباد، ولا يسقط الحقوق أنفسها، **فمن كان عليه صلاة أو كفارة ونحوها من حقوق الله تعالى, لا تسقط عنه**؛ لأنها حقوق لا ذنوب، إنما الذنب تأخيرها، فنفس التأخير يسقط بالحج, لا هي نفسها، فلو أخرها بعده، تجدد إثم آخر
>
> <sup>— [Kashshaaf al-Qinaa’](https://shamela.ws/book/622/2733#p1)</sup>

> وليس مراد القائل بأنه يكفرها أنه يسقط عنه قضاء ما لزمه من العبادات وتركه والمظالم والدين، **وإنما مراده أنه يكفر إثم تأخير ذلك، فإذا فرغ منه طولب بقضاء ما لزمه**، فإن لم يفعل مع قدرته فقد ارتكب الآن الكبيرة الأخرى
>
> <sup>— [رسالة الصغائر والكبائر](https://archive.org/details/ibn-nuceym-es-sagair-vel-kebair/page/n51/mode/2up?view=theater)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The sin of not doing them can be forgiven by doing tawba and doing them.
In other words, one should compensate for the missed actions